# How to print out an altered dynamic array

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays, println

I think I have swapped the first and last numbers of a dynamic array with each other and am at a total loss as to how to print the array with the numbers swapped.

Ideally, with the program working, the user is supposed to enter in the number of numbers they want to enter and then they will type each number in individually. **Then it is supposed to output** (along with standard deviation, the mean, and the original array order) **the array in order, except the first number entered and the last number entered are switched**. How would you go about printing the new array with the switched numbers?

Here is my code so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.Math;

    public class Project_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
    int N = scan.nextInt();
    float sd, mean;
    float Sum = 0;
    float Square = 0;
    float [] numbs = new float[N];

    System.out.println("Enter your numbers below: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        numbs[i] = scan.nextFloat();
        Sum += numbs[i];
    }
    mean = Sum/N;

    scan.close();

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        Square = (numbs[j] - mean) * (numbs[j] - mean);
    }   
    sd = (float)Math.sqrt(Square/N);

    System.out.println("The mean is: " + mean);
    System.out.println("The standard deviation is: " + sd);

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){
        if (k == N-1){
            System.out.print(numbs[k]);
        }else{
            System.out.print(numbs[k] + ", ");
        }

    }

    float lastNumb = numbs[numbs.length-1];
    numbs[numbs.length-1] = numbs[0];
    numbs[0] = lastNumb;

  }

}
```

Comment: If you're asking how to print an array, there's a lot of superfluous information cluttering the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As @shmosel wrote : post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the integers by doing the following,

```
int temp = numbs[N-1];
numbs[N-1] = numbs[0];
numbs[0] = temp;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that I would just have to enter another simple if statement to print it out. I was confused as to where the edited array was saving to, not realizing that it was just saving to the original array. Thank you all for the help.

In the end this is what I used for the code (in regards to my program specifically):

```
    float lastNumb = numbs[numbs.length-1];
    numbs[numbs.length-1] = numbs[0];
    numbs[0] = lastNumb;

    for (int g = 0; g < N; g++){
        if (g == N-1){
            System.out.print(numbs[g]);
        }else{
            System.out.print(numbs[g] + ", ");
        }
```

Heres the output:

```
    How many numbers would you like to enter? 5
    Enter your numbers below: 
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    The mean is: 3.0
    The standard deviation is: 0.8944272
    1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 
    5.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0
```